# Horizontal scroll problems in bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please help me remove the horizontal scroll of bootstrap3 which comes with classes "col-*".
This code doesn't work anymore
`.row{margin-left:0;margin-right:0}`

***here is my html markup***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="dist/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet/less" media="screen">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>



     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>...</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/less.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

***and here is the css code***

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: normal;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline:0;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{
font-weight: normal;    
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you send some code... Else, for me, everything works even with 'col-'...

Comment: And what's wrong with it?

Comment: As of bootstrap3 it should be `.row { margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;}` don't know where you have found the css above

Comment: It does not work with the latest upgraded version of bootstrap3. If you doownload it, you'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply messed up the hierarchy of your div tags a bit.

You need to wrap the `.row` inside the `.container`, not the other way around. Wrap the `.jumbotron` (or any other custom class that you want to go full width as a background) around the container:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>         
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YdRd2/7/

When you post questions here, try to include a JSFiddle that shows your problem (as isolated as possible). Fork this fiddle here to have Bootstrap already included: http://jsfiddle.net/SjfzQ/

Hope this helps.

Edit: Forgot to mention that in this case you wouldn't even need the row anyway, since you're just going full width:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
  </div>         
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YdRd2/8/

Comment: Thank you it works.
But from semantic side it is a little bit wrong because our column-container is "col" and class container just makes the content centered, so it is't right putting col inside the container.

Comment: @DavidKhasikyan: Check the source code of this example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/ 
You'll find that both patterns I listed above are used in this example, and exactly in the same way.